# why couldn't I get value through Ajax call?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I've created one Ajax function like this:

```
function searchPlanAjax(url){ 

        jQuery('#loader').css('display','block');
        var plan = jQuery('.rad').val();
        var site = url+"fbilling_details/subscription";
        jQuery.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: site,
               data: "plan="+plan,
               //data: "business_name="+val+"&bs="+bs,
               success: function(msg){

                   jQuery('#loader').css('display','none');
               }
           });
    }
```

Which I'm calling on radio button's onclick:

```
<?php echo $form->text(BILLING_DETAIL.'][id_plan', array('type'=>'radio', 'value'=>$val[PLAN]['id'], 'id'=>'id_plan_'.$val[PLAN]['id'], 'class'=>'rad','onclick'=>'searchPlanAjax('."'".SITE_NAME.ROOT_FOLDER_NAME."'".')')); ?>
```

The Ajax call will be processed in controller of cakePHP like this:

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['plan'])){
            $search_plan = $this->{PLAN}->find("all",array("conditions"=>array("id=".$_REQUEST['plan'])));

            $this->set('search_plan',$search_plan);
        }
```

but I couldn't get value in $search_plan variable. thanks if anybody can help.

Comment: $_REQUEST['plan'] is set correctly, right?

Comment: can you see the value being posted in the firebug

Comment: try debugging . . . alert the plan, as it received or not ... your code is perfectly valid.

Comment: @3nigma Guys, I've got the solution. its var plan = jQuery('.rad:checked').val(); instead of var plan = jQuery('.rad').val();
that is, missing 'checked'.

Comment: @kuroir Guys, I've got the solution. its var plan = jQuery('.rad:checked').val(); instead of var plan = jQuery('.rad').val();
that is, missing 'checked'.

Comment: @Hameed Guys, I've got the solution. its var plan = jQuery('.rad:checked').val(); instead of var plan = jQuery('.rad').val();
that is, missing 'checked'.

Answer (score 0):

Look at conditions in your find query

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['plan'])){
        $search_plan = $this->{PLAN}->find("all",array("conditions"=>array("id" => $_REQUEST['plan'])));

        $this->set('search_plan',$search_plan);
    }
```